# restricting bad words in Drupal comment control module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have added comment control module in my drupal site. It works fine by picking the bad words. But the issue is it is picking the word that has the same set.

Ex:It is picking "butt" as well as "butter" which i don't want to happen for butter.Is this a known issue for all or can it be fixed.

comments welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can try another solutions https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36257/drupal-7-comment-moderation-modules or switch to Disqus solution and disable core drupal comments